# what this code contain when I press the F12 button on public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

what this code contain when I press the F12 button IdentityUser.

```
 #region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll, v1.0.0.0
    // E:\10-31\test\System\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll
    #endregion

    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
    {
        public class IdentityUser : IUser
        {
            public IdentityUser();
            public IdentityUser(string userName);

            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
            public virtual string Id { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
            public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
            public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
            public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

what this code contain when I press the F12 button IdentityUser.

Comment: It's a representation of what methods are available in this class, which is part of the AspNet EF addons, judging by the namespace. I believe it's constructed by the VS IDE from symbols.